# Estimating Complex derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, estimation

Consider the following problem.

If $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}||z|<1\}$, and $f:D\rightarrow D$ is analytic with $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{3}$, then find the maximum value of $|f'\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)|$.

I am clue less as to how to proceed with this question.

I have tried thinking in terms of Cauchy's formula and the inequality arising out of it. But, that is given for a function with known bound.

I also went through the book, bak and newman complex analysis which is mentioned in the post [Ununderstood estimating of $|f({3\over 4})|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201706/ununderstood-estimating-of-f3-over-4). However, this method also requires the function $f$ to be bounded.

Please give a hint on how to proceed with this.

Comment: Every function $f:D\to D$ is bounded.

Comment: @Sumanta, Even if it's bounded, without knowing the bound, how can we proceed? can you give a hint on how to proceed please?

Comment: You know the bound. The codomain of $f$ is $D$, not $\Bbb C$.